# X-Cart Pro Module to display seller information in product detail page

Tags: module, x-cart

I am using X-Cart Pro 4.4.5.

While displaying the details of product when user clicks on any product, i want to display the Seller info as well, that who is selling that product.

See below link how X-Cart displays its product detail:
http://demo.x-cart.com/demo_pro/Three-Stone-Princess-Cut-Diamond-Ring.html

And now see below link to get idea how seller info should be included, it will show the vendor name ofr e.g,  "**Ships from/sold by World Wide Stereo (Who's this?)**"
http://www.buy.com/prod/mirage-nanosat-5-0-black/215492968.html

Now question is, do we have any module ready for displaying the seller info in product detail page?

Answer (score 0):

We are not aware of such mods I fear. Try to find something at http://marketplace.x-cart.com/addons-modules/

But displaying a seller/provider's name in product description page is not a big customization of X-Cart. Each product in X-Cart comes with seller data and you just need to edit product.tpl template file to display "provider" info where you need.